# TimeZone in different browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

i know it was asked a hundred of times how to change timezone in javaScript, My problem is that time zone is displayed different in FireFox and IE, 4 hours difference(my difference with UTC)

Here is my code:

```
var startDate  = new Date(rec[ns.$startDate]);
var utc = startDate.getTime() + startDate.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;
return new Date(utc);
```

maybe there is another way, for example get timezone from a string...

Comment: Could you please show what each browser gives you? Include Chrome as well for full coverage of the Big 3 (or go better and include Opera and Safari to see how widespread the issue is).

Comment: it's a web-service with time displayed in some places

Comment: Did you write any of the web service? If so, ALWAYS pass your DateTimes as UTC strings because of this kind of stuff. I had one once and the browser had its Time Zone, then when the server parsed it, it added its time zone. It had to go through another conversion (for some reason), and at the end, the time was about 14 hours off, and that was just East Coast US stores.

Answer (score 0):

try to use another variable to getTimeOffset...

```
var startDate  = new Date(rec[ns.$startDate]);
var d = new Date();
var utc = startDate.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;
return new Date(utc);
```

Comment: unfortunatelly, it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need the current time zone of the user in the form of string.

Try this code:

`Date().match(/GMT.\d+/).toString()`